# 404 not fount deploying django with apache on digitalocean

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/Debian_Install_Django_Apache2.md). When I try to open my IP address in my web browser, I got the Apache default page and when I navigate to `/admin`, I got 404 not found.

Here is my configuration: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `VirtualHost` is likely not used as you have `ServerName localhost` which wouldn't be resolved if accessing via its actual exposed hostname. Instead, there is probably an earlier `VirtualHost` which it is defaulting to, because if Apache can't do the name based virtual host matching, it will use the first `VirtualHost` it finds.

Change `ServerName` to use the actual exposed hostname you are accessing it as, or disable the other `VirtualHost` so there is only one.